# How to interpret Fueter's description of Diophantine equations with no rational points?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm an amateur mathematician so please forgive me if this is a basic question, but could you help me understand the meaning of the following snippet from a journal article (referring to work of Fueter):

[image]

Isn't 2mod9 equal to 2? How does this allow me to calculate a collection of delta k values? In the second statement, is it (8mod16 or 12mod16) or is it (8 or 12mod16? What does the 3 cross hk mean?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Those are *congruences* in abused notation, i.e. $\Delta \equiv 2\pmod{\!9}\,$  means $\, 9\mid \Delta-2,\,$ etc.

Comment: Ryan, Fueter seems to be from 1930. What is the source of your quote?

Comment: here is a paper by Cassels that mentions your guy https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485888565

Comment: $3\nmid h_k$ means "$3$ is not a divisor of $h_k$".

Comment: Thanks for your comments Bill, Will, and Lord Shark. This has helped!